# Some SKUs not returning the product details through REST API using get / update method in Magento2.1.3

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api, rest-api

Am trying to update the product details from third party machine to magento 2.1.3 using REST API.
here some of the SKUs not returning the details while get/update and then i logged that SKUs and checked in admin, it was available.

I dont know is there any mistake in skus fomrats.

Magento admin allowed to save the products using these kind of sku formats(ABCD (20-B), ABCD/20) in admin side :), we have many SKUs like that.

**Details:**

**Requested url**: `http://{base url}/index.php/rest/all/V1/products/{sku}` using OAuth 1.0

**Method**: `GET`

```
Skus list   | response:
ABCDE       | {"id":123,....}
ABCD123     | {"id":123,....}
ABCD (20-B) | {"message": "Invalid signature"}
```

Is any sku format suggested by magento doc?

Please suggest any solution to get works.

Thanks